# Simple bootloader [real mode - 16 bit, nasm] - trying to read some keystrokes and print it to the screen

Tags: assembly, nasm, interrupt, bootloader, bios

I started recently to get more interested in bootloaders, I was trying to write my own and something went wrong, with the combination of print and read. 
it seems like I'm overwriting the next variable, then I can't print anymore.

```
org 0x7c00 ; starting address

mov si, msg
call print_string ; here's it printing fine

mov si, save
call read_string ; here's everything going fine
mov si, save
call print_string ; but here's something somehow broken
mov si, msg
call print_string ; and now it's not printing the second message (I guess I'm overwriting the "0x00" byte) 

jmp $ ; infinate loop

print_string:
    pusha
    print_char:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, [si] ; pass one byte as an argument
        int 0x10 ; print to the screen
        inc si ; inc si to point to the next byte
        cmp al, 0x00 ; compare with 0
        jne print_char  
    popa
    ret

read_string:
    pusha
    read_char:
        mov ah, 0x00
        int 0x16 ; read keystroke
        mov BYTE [si], al ; store into the passed argument(for future use)
        mov ah, 0x0e
        int 0x10 ; print the char(while typing)
        inc si ; point to the next byte
        cmp al, 0x0d ; check if 'enter' has pressed 
        jne read_char
    mov BYTE [si], 0x0a
    inc si ; point to the next byte
    mov BYTE [si], 0x0d ; new line
    inc si ; point to the next byte
    mov BYTE [si], 0x00 ; last byte
    popa
    ret

save: db "" 
msg: db "input:", 0x00
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; padding
dw 0xaa55 ; magic
```

The input I get(before reading, imagine I'm pressing "lol" there):

```
input:_
```

and then(after reading):

```
lolput: lol
 lol
 _
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me, I've search around the internet about 3 days, but nothing too helpful was found.
Let me know if you've some good resources or books, or any other suggestions.
I hope I made the problem clear enough.

Comment: You don't reserve any space for `save`. Instead of `db ""`, use something like `times 100 db 0` (or however many bytes you want to reserve).

Comment: I tried and the third print works but it's printing the second one on the first one. like that:  `lolput: lol\ninput: _`, but thanks! it solved half the problem!